# How to restore an overwritten module reference to the original module when importing it?

Tags: python, odoo

When importing a Python module inside my own Odoo model, I noticed that the module is somehow corrupted or overwritten by Odoo. Here's some quick test code:

```
import odoo.tools.safe_eval as impmod
print(impmod)
```

When I launch this code in a separate Python console (Visual Studio Code), it prints the expected result:

```
<module 'odoo.tools.safe_eval' from '/home/odoo/odoo13/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py'>
```

However, when the same code is being executed inside Odoo environment during Odoo boot process, the printout is different:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x7f7e8e0ec8c8>
```

When I attempt to execute the function `impmod()`, it indeed behaves as the `safe_eval` function.

The module `safe_eval` happens to have a function defined with the same name.
So, my assumption is that some other code inside Odoo Python files is importing `safe_eval` module and then somehow overwriting it in some nasty way, so that `safe_eval` module reference is replaced by the function `safe_eval`, and thus I cannot access `safe_eval` as a module anymore, even when I import it as a module in my code.

The good thing is that when I access the same module through sys:

```
import sys, importlib
sysmod = sys.modules.get('odoo.tools.safe_eval', sys)
print(sysmod)
```

it prints the expected result:

```
<module 'odoo.tools.safe_eval' from '/home/odoo/odoo13/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py'>
```

So, at least the module was not replaced with the function in the `sys.modules` registry and I still can access it this dirty way.

Still, it leaves me very confused.

**How is it possible that some code can mess up module registry so badly that it is not possible to import the module correctly anymore?**

What am I missing here? I'm far from an expert in Python.

**Is there any way to recover from the situation to make `import odoo.tools.safe_eval as impmod` working as expected?**

Python version in both Odoo and Visual Studio Code is 3.6.9.

Comment: is the safe_eval module not work correctly in odoo?

Comment: @SDBot it works correctly, but I cannot access other functions inside the safe_eval module using simple `import odoo.tools.safe_eval` because then safe_eval always becomes the function and not the module itself. Normally, when using `import something` entire module is imported, and not a single function. But Odoo does something weird and replaces the module with the function; therefore I wanted to know how is that even possible and how to get to the module reference using `import` and not `sys.modules.get`.

Comment: it probably not an issue with odoo but python it self,

Comment: and does it really matter? if you want the methods inside safe_eval file you can use this: ```from odoo.tools.safe_eval import *```

Comment: @SDBot Actually, there is some more complications to that - I wanted to access private `_` variables inside the module. With * syntax I cannot do that because the module has `__all__` defined to limit `*` imports. So, the only way to access those internal vars is to have access to the module, but I cannot access it because Odoo has overwritten the module. It definitely is some Odoo-specific issue because I can import the same module just fine outside of Odoo. Odoo somewhere overwrites it.